# Meteor import SVG as React's component

Tags: reactjs, svg, meteor, async-await, assets

I can't do an explicit `import svg from './path/to/file.svg'` in a Meteor-React project.

According to this post "[import svg files inside meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792082/import-svg-files-inside-meteor)", this piece of code should solve the problem:

**server/main.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'svg.get'(data) {
        return Assets.getText(data.path);
    }
});
```

**client/main.js**

```
const getSVG = async (path) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Meteor.call('svg.get', { path }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) reject('Something went wrong');
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}

const SVG = await getSVG('some/path/relative/to/private/file.svg')
```

But it isn't working for me in Meteor 1.7+, I'm getting this error:

```
I20180606-11:42:09.264(-3)? Exception while invoking method 'svg.get' Error: Unknown asset: /var/www/coreui-meteor-react/public/img/brand/logo.svg
I20180606-11:42:09.392(-3)?     at getAsset (/var/www/coreui-meteor-react/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:329:19)
I20180606-11:42:09.392(-3)?     at Object.getText (/var/www/coreui-meteor-react/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:340:16)
I20180606-11:42:09.393(-3)?     at MethodInvocation.svg.get (server/main.js:6:21)
I20180606-11:42:09.393(-3)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1767:12)
I20180606-11:42:09.393(-3)?     at DDP._CurrentMethodInvocation.withValue (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:19)
I20180606-11:42:09.393(-3)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1189:12)
I20180606-11:42:09.394(-3)?     at DDPServer._CurrentWriteFence.withValue (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:46)
I20180606-11:42:09.394(-3)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1189:12)
I20180606-11:42:09.394(-3)?     at Promise (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:715:46)
I20180606-11:42:09.394(-3)?     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
I20180606-11:42:09.395(-3)?     at Session.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:689:23)
I20180606-11:42:09.395(-3)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:43
```

Even if I add the await keyword here:

```
const logo = await svg.get('/img/brand/logo.svg');
```

It throws this error:

```
While building for web.browser:
   client/containers/DefaultLayout/DefaultHeader.js:9:13: await is a reserved word (9:13)

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
   client/containers/DefaultLayout/DefaultHeader.js:9:13: /var/www/coreui-meteor-react/client/containers/DefaultLayout/DefaultHeader.js: await is a reserved word (9:13)

   7 |
   8 |
   >  9 | const logo = await svg.get('/img/brand/logo.svg');
   |              ^
   10 | const sygnet = await svg.get('/img/brand/sygnet.svg');
   11 |
   12 | const propTypes = {
```

***Any solution for doing a classic SVG import from React in Meteor-React project?***

Answer (score 2):

You're probably specifying a wrong path.

According to documentation of [Assets.getText](https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html#Assets-getText) the argument must be:

> The path of the asset, relative to the application's **private** subdirectory.

Based on the error, you're providing `/var/www/coreui-meteor-react/public/img/brand/logo.svg` where you should do only `img/brand/logo.svg` and move the file from `public` to `private` directory of your app.

If you want to access some file from `public` directory you can do it at any time on the client, using a direct link. In this case `your-app.com/img/brand/logo.svg`

---

Second error is unrelated. To use `await` keyword your code must be inside an `async` function, it's not allowed in regular functions or in top level code.